# Timestamp assertions in JMeter

Tags: multithreading, jdbc, timer, jmeter, assertion

I have thousands of requests and two assertions in JMeter.

The structure of my thread is as follows.

Main screen:

[image: Main Screen]

Error screen:

[image: Error Screen]

- I'm currently simulating 5,000 users.
- The HTTP service I'm testing is an end-point without a screen.
- I send a JSON in the BODY, and it writes the record in the bank, I am sending only valid data, fixed values, except the UUID that is dynamic for each request.

  ```
  {
     "program": "001",
     "level": "INFO",
     "event": "REGISTER_ALUNO",
     "message":{
     "code": "$ {uuid}",
        "operation": "Student register",
        "Name": "John SQL SERVER10",
        "enroll": "123"
     }
  }
  ```

**What's happening:**

The requests are usually done and my Bean Shell UUID_GENERATOR is also done.

However, my JDBC request `ASSERT SQL SERVER INSERT` begins to give errors by the following fact: it validates in the database if the values ​​passed in the request were entered, but due to the large number of requests, some assertions are validating values ​​that have not yet been entered in the bank because of the delay between the requests, resulting in errors in the assertion.

What I need is some form of user a timer, for the assertions to be made, after the completion of the request that makes the recording in the bank.
 
Since JMeter runs the calls asynchronously, I could not execute something like this.

First UUID, AFTER REQUEST, AFTER, ASSERTS.

I've tried using some fixed and dynamic timers, but some assertions still remain out of the question.

Does anyone have any controller or timer tips that I can use to make the assertion be done successfully without "rushing"?

Note: The same errors occur on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, sampler `HTTP Request` puts something on a queue to insert into DB, but insert may take time. Meanwhile your `HTTP Request` returns because it accepted the work (even though the work is not done yet), and continues to next sampler `ASSERT SQL SERVER INSERT`, which may reach SQL server **before** the work submitted by `HTTP Request` actually got into DB.

If this is correct, then you can use 3 options:

1. Retry `ASSERT SQL SERVER INSERT` a few times, without failing, until it actually performs verification, or timeout is reached. That can be done by While Controller and a variable that tells it when to quit (i.e. when `ASSERT SQL SERVER INSERT` was successful or max number of retries was reached):

   ```
   JSR223 Sampler; code: 
       vars.put("rerun", "true");
   While Controller; condition: ${rerun}
       ASSERT SQL SERVER INSERT
           JSR223 Post-Processor; code: 
               if(SampleResult.isSuccessful() /* || add condition to limit number of retries here */)
                   vars.put("rerun", "false");
   ```
2. Implement DB stored procedure to handle the wait. I.e. whatever query you are running is made into stored procedure together with wait and retries. This will allow you to avoid multiple round trips to the server.
3. Introducing one of the timers (e.g. `Constant Timer`) or `Test Action` (with pause) **under** `ASSERT SQL SERVER INSERT` is another possibility, but as with all delays it will force `ASSERT SQL SERVER INSERT` to wait even if it doesn't need to.